# how to filter an element of array inside array of objects in java-script without using for loop?

Tags: javascript

my data. data also has empty entries

```
const aadharData = [
  {
    firstName: "Ritam",
    lastName: "Singhal",
    address: {
      location: "rampur",
      state: "up",
    },
    hasDrivingLicense: false,
    emails: ["abc@outlook.com", "efg@gamil.com", "ghj@gmail.com"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Siddarth",
    lastName: "Singhal",
    address: {
      location: "chandigarh",
      state: "haryana",
    },
    hasDrivingLicense: false,
    emails: ["fgdfg@gmail.com"],
  },
];
```

**1.** what I managed to filter out was a list of emails and fullname. with following code

```
let gmailList = [];
aadharData.forEach((info) => {
  if (info.emails) {
    let fullname = info.firstName + " " + info.lastName;
    let email = info.emails;
    gmailList.push({ fullname, email });
  }
});
```

**2.** I want to filter only those emailID that are gmails. however, I don't know how to iterate inside the property. I tried using forEach, some, and filter inside forEach but that doesn't seem to work or at least I don't know how to use them effectively. my assignment states I can't use for loop. finally, i want results in the format as

```
 { fullname, gmail }
```

example

```
{ fullname: "Mayank Attri", email: ["abc@gmail.com"] };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve the result using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). You can filter the email as

```
o.emails && o.emails.filter((e) => e.match(/gmail.com$/))
```

```js
const aadharData = [{
    firstName: "Ritam",
    lastName: "Singhal",
    address: {
      location: "rampur",
      state: "up",
    },
    hasDrivingLicense: false,
    emails: ["abc@outlook.com", "efg@gamil.com", "ghj@gmail.com"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Siddarth",
    lastName: "Singhal",
    address: {
      location: "chandigarh",
      state: "haryana",
    },
    hasDrivingLicense: false,
    emails: ["fgdfg@gmail.com"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Mukul",
    lastName: "Gaddiyan",
    address: {
      location: "lucknow",
      state: "up",
    },
    hasDrivingLicense: false,
  },
  {
    firstName: "Mayank",
    lastName: "Attri",
    address: {
      location: "alwar",
      state: "rajasthan",
    },
    hasDrivingLicense: true,
    emails: ["abc@yahoo.com"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Akash",
    lastName: "Agarwal",
    address: {
      location: "gurgaon",
      state: "haryana",
    },
    hasDrivingLicense: true,
    emails: ["abc@gmail.com", "efg@yahoo.com", "ghj@outlook.com"],
  },
];

const result = aadharData.map((o) => ({
  fullname: `${o.firstName} ${o.lastName}`,
  emails: o.emails && o.emails.filter((e) => e.match(/gmail.com$/)),
}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Updated: If you want result your resultant array contains only `emails` if there are more than one emails

```js
const aadharData = [{
    firstName: "Ritam",
    lastName: "Singhal",
    address: {
      location: "rampur",
      state: "up",
    },
    hasDrivingLicense: false,
    emails: ["abc@outlook.com", "efg@gamil.com", "ghj@gmail.com"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Siddarth",
    lastName: "Singhal",
    address: {
      location: "chandigarh",
      state: "haryana",
    },
    hasDrivingLicense: false,
    emails: ["fgdfg@gmail.com"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Mukul",
    lastName: "Gaddiyan",
    address: {
      location: "lucknow",
      state: "up",
    },
    hasDrivingLicense: false,
  },
  {
    firstName: "Mayank",
    lastName: "Attri",
    address: {
      location: "alwar",
      state: "rajasthan",
    },
    hasDrivingLicense: true,
    emails: ["abc@yahoo.com"],
  },
  {
    firstName: "Akash",
    lastName: "Agarwal",
    address: {
      location: "gurgaon",
      state: "haryana",
    },
    hasDrivingLicense: true,
    emails: ["abc@gmail.com", "efg@yahoo.com", "ghj@outlook.com"],
  },
];

const result = aadharData.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (curr.emails) {
    const emails = curr.emails.filter((e) => e.match(/gmail.com$/));
    emails.length &&
      acc.push({
        fullname: `${curr.firstName} ${curr.lastName}`,
        emails,
      });
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
/* This is not a part of answer. It is just to give the output fill height. So IGNORE IT */

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. can you please tell me what you used ? the $ symbol i dont know what it is.  if you can refer me some link it would be great help. also code runs here but on vs code it shows error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined
    at c:\Users\JAY SARDAR\project\es6\functionUp\firstproject\src\Routes\index.js:82:22
    `

Comment: i got the similar error when i tried to use info.emails.some(condition) also i tried info.emails.filter, but i got same error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined`

Comment: also its not specific to vs code.  i got same error on codepen https://codepen.io/blue-berd/pen/PojqzdL

Comment: @JaySardar I've updated the answer, `$` is used as [Template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Error was because some objects in array doesn't have the `emails` property.

Comment: Please let me know is this what you want?

Comment: can you refer me more resources? i still dont understand why there is empty array after return in new solution you gave

Comment: If the `email` array doesn't have any element that ends with `gmail.com` then I give an empty array because I've used [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: That's why there is another solution I've already added, that will contain only those objects that contains at least single string that ends with `gmail.com`